# Kafka topic retention time for different consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka

For a Kafka topic there can be different consumer groups like CG1, CG2 and CG3. Each consumer groups may have different way of processing the message.

How to define topic retention time different for different consumer groups as they would like to have different retention times  ? Like for CG1 it will be 3 mins, for CG2 it will be 7 mins and for CG3 it will be 10 mins

May be we can consider the maximum most and keep it for 10 mins.

One approach in this case is to have different topics for different consumer groups. But that means unnecessary topic creation for similar kind of event payload and for just to change the retention time.

Is there any other way to solve the problem ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? The retention is a topic setting, there's no need (nor way) to set a different retention based on the consumer group. Pick the longest retention you need from the consumers add a bit of leeway and that's the topic retention. Keep in mind that the longer the retention period, the more storage that is needed. Having separate topics is a bad solution as that will require extra processing, network and storage.

Comment: Message in topic won't be deleted after consumer consumes the message right it will be deleted based on the retention policy that you are setting for topic. There can be any number of consumers consuming your message but message is deleted based on the retention policy. So please select the higher retention interval by considering all consumers which are consuming to topic and set the retention policy.

Answer (score 1):

> define topic retention time different for different consumer groups

This isn't possible. Retention time is a topic setting, completely unrelated to any consumer functionality.

The producer can manually set a timestamp in the record when it's created, then the broker will inspect that time, and decide if to keep the record. But your producer wouldn't know there's different consumer groups, so cannot set more than one timestamp.

Your producers could duplicate data across different topics, however, each with different retention

It's not really recommended to put retention on the order of minutes, however, without slowing down your broker overall since the disks will almost constantly be deleting data under any significant load

The other workaround would be to dump the data somewhere else, such as a database where you can query like `WHERE time BETWEEN NOW() and (NOW() - '10 minutes')`. This would have the added benefit of being faster than consuming a whole Kafka topic start-to-"end", with the tradeoff of eventual consistency